# Remove any element if it's count is bigger than x amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've looked around a bit and I cannot seem to find out how to remove a DOM element if its count gets over 50 amount. Basically it's similar to a chat.

JS

```
function append(aVal) {
    document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML += "<br/>" + aVal;
}
```

Usage

```
appendvalues("<span>Your message " + message + ".</span>");
```

HTML

```
<div id="elem" class="container"></div>
```

I'm trying to remove the br & span tags. I feel that making a class for the span tag would be better since I have other span tags on the page.

Comment: Although you tagged your question with jQuery, are you looking for a pure JS or a jQuery solution?

Comment: It seems to be more than _similar_ to chat. This type of design will not get you very far. You better create logic and have the UI reflect that. In this case, have a `ChatClient`, store the message strings and other relevant data and have the UI reflect changes to messages. Then, if you want to remove older messages, to truncate beyond a certain point, you can remove the DOM nodes associated with those messages. Another thing, manipulating the innerHTML of the container is not advised. You are much better off using DOM API to add the nodes to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do it FIFO...

```
function append(aVal) {
    var el = document.getElementById('elem');
    el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br/>" + aVal);

    var spans = el.getElementsByTagName("span");
    if (spans.length > 50) {
        el.removeChild(spans[0].nextSibling);
        el.removeChild(spans[0]);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `.insertAdjacentHTML` instead of `.innerHTML +=...`. This is a much less destructive way to add content from HTML.

Comment: Thanks you didn't add a removal for the br tags. I added it myself though.

Comment: @ECMAScript: Oh, yeah I guess that makes sense. I'll update so that it's complete.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
$("#elem > span:gt(50)").remove();
```